# Does the c++ compiler combine multiple algorithms into one loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-optimization

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int main () {
 int myints[] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};

 // using default comparison:
 std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *std::min_element(myints,myints+7) << '\n';
 std::cout << "The largest element is "  << *std::max_element(myints,myints+7) << '\n';
}
```

Will the compiler optimize the above into one loop? Or is it better to write in one for-loop?

Comment: This sounds like a micro-optimisation question...

Comment: There's no such thing as *the* C++ compiler. There is your C++ compiler and there is my C++ compiler. Yours might not optimize and mine might. The only way to tell for your compiler is for you to examine the code that your compiler generates. And I agree with Oli, you should be worrying about other things than this.

Comment: Potentially it could. Theoretically, it could also replace the two calls with vectorized versions of the instructions, so the "for" loops would look very differently. If a single loop is important to you, you should write it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is like in many things, it depends.

**Yes** if the compiler decides to fuse the loops together because it will propably improve the runtime performance based on heuristics.

**No** is much more propably because there are only 7 elements and a [loop-fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fusion) would make no sense.

Note also that a fusion makes no sense because ihe operation is only one time executed (in that example).

---

To get a more detailed answer look at the assembly output of your compiler and compare the output of different compilers.

---

Another thing is, why care about such micro optimizations if it doesn't boost the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually have much bigger vectors, and 12 separate std::transform with lambda functions in c++11.

Comment: I'm downvoting because your answer reads as "The compiler does loop fusion if the compiler does loop fusion, and it also might not... also don't micro-optimize." This sounds awfully much like a dismissive tautology, rather than an informed answer.

Comment: @Veedrac should I make a list with all possible current and future compilers with all flags... sure the answer isn't clear but it can be framed as "depends on the optimisations possible by the compiler and settings"

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the compiler. For example, my compiler (`g++ 4.7.3` on `x86_64`) does not, keeping two separate loops (when compiling with `-O3`):

```
_main:
;=== initialization code omitted ===
        jmp     L2
L3:
        movl    (%rax), %edx
        cmpl    %edx, %ebx
        cmovg   %edx, %ebx
L2:
        addq    $4, %rax
        cmpq    %rbp, %rax
        jne     L3
;=== output code omitted ===
        jmp     L8
L6:
        movl    (%rax), %ecx
        cmpl    %ecx, (%rdx)
        cmovl   %rax, %rdx
L8:
        addq    $4, %rax
        cmpq    %rbp, %rax
        jne     L6
;=== output code omitted ===
```

Answer (score 3):

Optimizations are, by definitions, not mandated by the Standard, therefore it really depends on the compiler... and a hoist of other conditions.

In your particular case though, I'd like to signal [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)... might come handy.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the pedanticism of the standard ≠ the compiler, whilst correct and useful, is no more than a side-comment to the actual issue. The point holds doubly for your second comment.